# What to do when I notice symptoms of mechanical printer failures?

Tags: printer, hardware-failure

I have a HP Deskjet 9300 connected with USB to a Jetdirect 175x box. The 9300 is kinda old. Its been here since prior to 04/2007. The Jetdirect was installed in 2008. The users of this printer have reported in the last week that everything still "works" but it is tremendously slow to print out documents.

The printer takes 10 minutes to spit out a test page when initiated under printer properties > print test page button.

The printer takes 10 minutes to print a "demonstration" page when you hold the paper feed button down. (This is what makes ME think that its a hardware problem because this isolates users and network issues and renders straight off of the demo page in the firmware.)

The printer rollers move a quarter turn every minute or two.

No loud noises or anything out of the ordinary that would make me think its having mechanical issues.

The jetdirect page shows no major packet failures or weird network traffic stats so I assume it is working fine. After all, it is forwarding jobs through the printer. Just at a very slow rate.

Anything else I can check out on this thing before I call it junk?

Comment: Can you ever get it to spin faster? Is there gunk or something else that prevents it from spinning?

Comment: When you say "The printer takes 10 minutes to print a demonstration page" does that mean it takes 10 minutes before it starts printing, or that it take 10 minutes to finish the print job (once it's started)?

Comment: It appears that all "normal" fast moving operations like moving the cartridge arm and pulling in new blank sheets into the feeder area are now very very slow. Watching the internal rollers there is one not moving but I am not totally sure it is supposed to move on power up. Or if the issue is bigger like stripped out teeth on a gear not engaging the roller. This thing is moving a lot slower than all other deskjets I deal with. In regards to the "10 minutes" the printer immediately starts blinking led's to indicate it is spooling the job but the print operation takes about 10 mins to complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Try to apply maintenance](https://superuser.com/questions/318230/how-do-i-maintain-a-printer), or get a professional to do it for you.

More specifically, [try this guidelines](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&taskId=125&prodSeriesId=295930&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=295930&objectID=c00019194) and let us know whether that helped.

Do you notice any mechanical damage?